# Codeigniter: Can I use $this->db->trans_start() and trans_complete with in my controller function?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have more than one model functions that are executed before transaction is completed. For example

```
$this->model_A->insert('....');
$this->model_C->insert('....');
$this->model_D->insert('....');
$this->model_E->update('....');
```

what is the best way to use trans_start() and trans_complete() so incase the process of insert or update is interrupted at any point the transaction can be rollback or committed accordingly...

Is there any possibility I can use these below lines in my controller? Like this?

```
$this->db->trans_start();

    $this->model_A->insert('....');
    $this->model_C->insert('....');
    $this->model_D->insert('....');
    $this->model_E->update('....');

$this->db->trans_complete();

OR

$this->model_A->trans_start();

    $this->model_A->insert('....');
    $this->model_C->insert('....');
    $this->model_D->insert('....');
    $this->model_E->update('....');

$this->model_A->trans_complete();
```

Is it a good practice if not what is the best way to handle such transactions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first alternative is proper.

Transaction logic is at the database level.  Codeigniter does not document doing it at the 'table' level ( see http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html).

Your second alternative does not make sense - the transaction encompasses different tables.

Comment: I am using $this->db->trans_start(); in first alternative with in controller, do you think it is the right thing to do?

Comment: Yes - the controller has the 'whole process point of view.  Codeigniter allows multi-table models but I do not think they are correct, in the spirit of MVC, in this particular example, unless the different tables are really part of a very closely linked update (or select).     But your question does not expose the actial data so it is hard to say if a multi-table model would be proper.  I do not like them.  Controllers are where the different models can get related and this makes your  intention clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I the mentioned approach the best/will work from within a model. In my case I have delete something and then run some SQL to recalculate the totals which a stored in another table. So something like the following in the model is a good approach?

```
$this->db->trans_start();
   $this->db->delete('table_name', $data);
   $this->another_model->recalculate_update_thing('....');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

I'd prefer to have them both in the same function in the model as the delete can be called from a couple of controllers.